# QScroller in QGraphicsView resets viewport origin (Qt 5.7)

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I have a simple subclass of QGraphicsView that I'd like to enhance with kinetic scrolling. My QGraphicsScene sceneRect is something like (origin = -12500,12500 w=25000, h=25000), so is centered on 0,0, but extends far negative and far positive. In the QGraphicsView, when I attempt:

```
if(clicked)
{
    // Enable kinetic effects -- should work, but doesn't
    QScroller::grabGesture(this->viewport(), QScroller::LeftMouseButtonGesture);

    // this behaves as I expect:
    // this->setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag);
}
```

When dragging, viewport's image truncates everything < 0,0 in Scene Coordinates, plus when I release the mouse, the viewport jumps so that the Scene 0,0 is located at the View 0,0 (upper left). When in this mode, the scroll bars work as expected. Hopefully, the picture included below will help...

Very confusing.

I've tried attaching the grab gesture to both the QGraphicsView and the QGraphicsView->viewport() and neither work as I expect...

[Picture of Before, During, After kinetic drag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDm4O.png)